# How to keep a GraphicsItem from being dragged outside of the scene?

Tags: c++, qt, draggable, scene, qgraphicsitem

I've created a graphicsitem in another class and it is movable. However, the user can move it outside of the scene.

How do I make it so that the item stops moving once it hits the edges of the scene?

Comment: By checking if the 2d x/y of the bounding box of your item is outside the window coordinates and disabling move. Make sure to make this check in projection space. This is done outside rendering.

Comment: You should use [QGraphicsItem::itemChange](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#itemChange). See the example in the docs.